# STEAM games on Wine or Windows VM

Tags: wine, games, steam, virtualization

I recently installed Steam on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine, but noticed not all games are available to me. I am looking to play a particular game H1Z1 which is not ported for Linux, so I was wondering if I install Steam on Wine, or through a Windows VM, if I can play a game that is not ported for Linux? If so , what would be the most stable & playable method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use wine but wine has a special branch for gaming (well more like a fork from wine :P ) called playonlinux, check it out!